# Replacing HTML on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on making my sidebar responsive. The problem is, I can't simply use CSS media queries because the two sidebar designs I have are so different that it can't be done (much text would need to be removed, etc). So what I have are two sidebar designs, one which should replace the other when the browser is resized.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    var tablet = 1240;

    /* If width of browser is less than 1240... */
    if (width < tablet) {

        /* Hide the non-tablet sidebar. */
        $('.sidebar:not(.tablet)').hide();

        /* If the tablet sidebar already exists on the page, show it. */
        if ($('.sidebar.tablet').length) {
            $('.sidebar.tablet').show();
        } else {

            /* If the tablet sidebar doesn't exist on the page, load it and append it to the body. */
            $.get("sidebar_tablet.php", function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
            });
        }
    }

    /* If width of browser is greater than 1240... */
    if (width > tablet) {

        /* Hide the tablet sidebar. */
        $('.sidebar.tablet').hide();

        /* Show the non-tablet sidebar. */
        $('.sidebar:not(.tablet)').show();
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I resize the browser to less than 1240px wide, it will load the tablet sidebar multiple times (I'm guessing because the check to see if the sidebar already exists or not is slower than the speed at which I resize the browser), even though I have a check to see if it already exists on the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can u make jsfiddle for complete code..

Comment: You could put both sidebars in the HTML at all times, hide one with a CSS `@media` query and `display: none` and then do the opposite when it gets to a smaller size.

Comment: why not use media queries instead of javascript? :O

Comment: @misterManSam I could, but that's loading more than I need to. Some users won't resize their browser for the duration of their time on the site.

Comment: @martinezjc It says why I can't use media queries in the second sentence of the question. There are simply too many differences in the sidebars.

Comment: You will use more resources with javascript then you will with redundant HTML

Comment: @misterManSam But that's _if_ they even resize.

Comment: Instead you can use one separated css file and load it specific for the target device

Comment: @martinezjc It's not just the CSS that changes, it's the layout of the HTML as well.

Comment: if they resize the media query will do the trick automatically :)

Comment: so, u can use two differents templates in that case :)

Comment: Resize the window [in this basic example](http://jsbin.com/yefoz/2/edit). You can `display: none` and `display: block` to show and hide based on screen size.

Comment: Decided to go with @misterManSam's solution. I'll have to run some tests to see if it's more efficient with his solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to expand on my comment above.

You *can* achieve this with `@media`. Have both sidebars in the HTML and use a combination of `display: none` and `display: block` to hide and show. The performance hit of having both the large and small sidebar in the HTML is basically non-existent - especially when compared to a javascript solution.

[This is the super basic example](http://jsbin.com/yefoz/2/edit). Resize to see the divs change.

HTML

```
<div class="big">
    I'm Big!
</div>

<div class="small">
    I'm Small
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
.big {
    background: #F00;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.small {
    background: #FF0;
    height: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  .big {
    display: block;
  }
    .small {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe loading the sidebar_tablet.php is taking some time, and you are resizing the browser before the request has finished.
You can add a var to flag wether you are done loading the sidebar_tablet.php or not.