# Styling lists so they are forced horizontal when vertical limit is reached

Tags: css

This is my first post here, I hope you can help.

I have a nav list that is inside a div with a specific height and width - 900x200.

What I need to do is keep the nav list vertical in the containing div until it reaches the 200 height limit then I need to force the next element in the nav to the right so it looks like columns.

Here's an example of my simple nav html:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="parent">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

So here, #nav will have a height of 200px. when one li.parent hits the 200px within the div, I need the following li.parent to be forced right and to the top again. 
The result might be 3 li.parents stacked in the first column and 2 in the next etc depending on how many children they each contain. Here's a link to a visual example of what I need it to do. Many thanks in advance!

[Visual example of what I need](http://ied.umbracodev.co.uk/images/nav.jpg)

Comment: some what have you tried show some of your style or just plunker it

Comment: #nav {visibility:hidden; position:absolute; width:840px; height:139px; background:url(../images/nav-bg-full.png) no-repeat; padding:47px 30px 15px; 30px;}
#nav h3 {background:url(../images/down-arrow.png) no-repeat right; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0 15px 0 0; display:inline-block; font-size:0.95em;}
#nav a.close {position:absolute; left:246px; top:13px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; font-size:0.8em;}

Comment: #nav ul li.parent {float:left; width:195px; display:block;}
#nav ul li {}
#nav ul li a {color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-size:0.8em;}
#nav ul li a.product-type {font-weight:bold; font-size:0.85em;}
#nav ul li a:hover {color:#000;}
#nav ul li ul {margin:0 0 20px 0;}

Comment: @Benjamin thanks, this css just horizontally aligns the li's

Comment: @Benjamin
[link](http://ied.umbracodev.co.uk/)
click the view range link

Answer (score 0):

Place your properties for the smaller height inside `@media all and (max-height: 200px) { }`

[Here is an example with your floats.](http://jsbin.com/jenubo/2/edit) You can drag the middle divider down to pull the output underneath and test the height.

CSS

```
@media all and (max-height: 200px) { 
    /* Your properties for a small height */
}
```

---

[Here is a basic example](http://jsbin.com/jenubo/1/edit) using CSS columns and `@media`. You can drag the middle divider down to pull the output underneath and test the height. When the height reaches `200px` the CSS columns take over. You of course don't need to use CSS columns, you could layout the lists with floats, inline-block, whatever.

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    width: 500px;
}

@media all and (max-height: 200px) {
    nav {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link1</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Link3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Link4</li>
    <li>Link4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work for me or i'm not getting it.
[View Example] (http://ied.umbracodev.co.uk/images/nav2.jpg)

The list in the example still stays in one column even though the nav is forced to 200px. I need it to auto start another column when it reaches the parent div height limit. Thanks again!

Comment: I see what you mean, if I adjust the broswer window to less than 200px the lists move to the right. However, all the lists get restyled horizontally rather than filling the columns before the next column is started. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean, could you place your current code into a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so I can see?

Comment: so, i need parent 2 to drop under parent 1 then if the 200px height is reached, the next (parent 3) would start the next column. List need to run vertically until height is reached then the next vertical column would start. Hope I'm being clear enough :-/

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5vrqggf/2/). You create a series of `@media` queries based on height and then change your CSS for each step (re-size the height to check). If you need to, you can also change your HTML and hide/show for each step. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270793/replacing-html-on-resize/25271405#25271405) is a good example of that.

Comment: Still doesn't do it. I understand that by changing media settings the columns will change but the order doesn't. The whole navigation still overflows the parent #nav http://ied.umbracodev.co.uk/images/nav.jpg is what im trying to achieve. As you can see from the image, absolute encoders is menu item 3. There's no room for it in column one within the #nav limits so it starts the 2nd column from the top